# What's a .duo file?

Tags: .net, file-extension

In a .NET/C# project, one of my *.exe files has a corresponding *.duo file.  (I didn't set up the build system.)  What is it?

Somebody suggested it was something like a user preferences file for the debugger, possibly?

Comment: Can you show us the contents of the file? Perhaps in hex format?

Answer (score 2):

I think it might mean database user options, because it seems to have some form of [relation with Microsoft Access](http://www.file-extensions.org/duo-file-extension).

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean .suo?
That stands for Visual Studio Solution User Options.

Comment: Hmm, I'd tried searching on a couple of those sites, which was apparently not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be [database related](http://www.file-extensions.org/duo-file-extension)

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find any info on the file extension : http://filext.com/alphalist.php?extstart=^D

Additionally - it does not appear to be a valid [Visual Studio file extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k0zafxb.aspx) - are you using any 3rd party tools that might generate this?  What are you using for source control?